# How to prevent kernel modules to load?

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

I'm fairly new in Linux, looking for a solution to entirely ban kernel module to load.

I know how to unload module but need to prevent it before module loads on boot.

Comment: it doesn't called process until it run.
so do you mean you want to prevent running a script or service ?

Comment: `chmod -x /path/to/program`

Comment: What kind of process are you talking of? How is it started? Why not simply deinstalling that service?

Comment: sorry my mistake, not a process but the modules to ban , there are some modules running on my new Linux box coming from a hosting provider, which I do not want to run. Presumably they are running cause some not needed hardware pieces are present, and do not really want to alter the kernel to remove them...

Comment: Do you mean modules (as in the title), or processes (as in the body)?

Comment: _I'm fairly new in Linux, looking for a solution to entirely ban kernel module to load._ sounds much like _I have no idea about this thing, but I want to meddle with its internals_. Doesn't look like a good idea. Maybe you tell us what you _actually_ want?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I've got my answer, I needed to prevent some kernel modules to load without altering kernel or using other than provided by Hosting provider, and I did manage it to prevent as per Wice22's advice. Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed. I don't think it needs more details or anything: it's just a simple question and doesn't need any more context than what was given.

Answer (score 8):

Check the module name first:

```
lsmod | less
```

Then let say loaded module name is my_proc_to_ban

go and create a script such as :

```
echo'
install my_proc_to_ban /bin/false
' >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

That will prevent to boot or run your module

or as in your case, server is yours and no one going to load the module
you can simply:

```
echo '
blacklist my_proc_to_ban
' >> /etc/modprobe.d/my_proc_to_ban.conf
```

That will prevent your module to load on boot, but you still be able to load it if needed on some stage.

Comment: ``lsmod | less`` is not going to get you process names. Did you want some invocation of ``ps(1)``?

Comment: On the assumption that the question actually is about kernel modules, this is a valid answer, but a little explanation of what's going on would improve it.

Answer (score 1):

A way to be sure is to remove or move the module from /lib/modules

You may also use /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

On kernel command line you may add

```
modprobe.blacklist=modname1,modname2,modname3
```

or

```
blacklist=modname1,modname2,modname3
```

source : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules#Blacklisting

Depending on which distribution you use : debian (and derivatives) may build a initrd which embeds modules that the script thinks are mandatory to boot the the system.

So you may have to rebuild the initrd image by running "update-initramfs -u".